# How to use the taken width and height in xml file in andorid?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have identified the width and height of the screen programatically. Now I want to use that width and height in my xml file. Kindly give me a way to achive this.

Here is my Activity class.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
        float width = display.widthPixels;
        float height = display.heightPixels;
        Toast.makeText(TestProjectActivity.this, "width and height is: "+width + ": "+height, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        float w = convertPixelsToDp(width, this);
        float h = convertPixelsToDp(height, this);

        Toast.makeText(TestProjectActivity.this, "DP" +w+":  "+h, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px,Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
        return dp;
    }
```

Now I want to send the **`w`** and **`b`** to the xml for the further work.

Any help would be appricieted?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't send those values to the xml layout file if I understood what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am developing the application which runs on any screen device. So the issue with the screen size. If I am setting the width of textview to 200dp, then its ok in my device but on other device,its not getting appear. So I just want a way where I can use this above detected width and height in my XML

Comment: If you require this kind of control then you would need, at runtime, to retrieve those views and based on the calculated dimensions set their dimensions. But sound as bad UI from an Android perspective.

Comment: yes but you can suggest me any link or clear it out that how can i do this.then it will be helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass information back to XML. At most, you can get your widget using `findViewById` and then programmatically set the widget size.

> I am developing the application which runs on any screen device. So the issue with the screen size. If I am setting the width of textview to 200dp, then its ok in my device but on other device,its not getting appear. So I just want a way where I can use this above detected width and height in my XML

You should then use a `LinearLayout` to give your image a size relative to the available width (like a percentage of the width of the screen

Here is how your XML would look (pseudo code)

```
LinearLayout (layout_width: match_parent, layout_height: wrap_content)
  ImageView (layout_width: 0dip, layout_height: wrap_content, layout_weight: 50)
  ImageView (layout_width: 0dip, layout_height: wrap_content, layout_weight: 50)
```

In the above example, each image view will take 50% of the screen width, no matter the number of pixels.

I think you need to Google a good tutorial about layouts in Android.

Comment: I have the idea about this.but every time setting the percentage on each and every widgets is not a good idea. Thats why I wanted to clear it out.